# Can't install modules, Cannot allocate memory error?

Tags: r, memory, amazon-ec2

I just launched a new `EC2` ubuntu `t1.micro`. I installed `R 3.1.2` and when I try to install any module I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, stderr = outfile) :
  system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
2: In install.packages("zoo") :
  installation of package ‘zoo’ had non-zero exit status
```

I read on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136264/unable-to-install-packages-system-call-failed-cannot-allocate-memory-instal) that this might be because of the swap memory, but in my case the memory is set to 60 which I think should be all right.

When I run `.libsPaths()` I get

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

At first R was complaining that it did not had permission to write on `/usr/lib/R/library`, but after I changed the directory permissions that error went away.

Any clue on how to get it to work will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hello @Amstell, actually in my question I quote that question and I say that that approach is not working for me and that is why I am asking a new question...

Comment: Yes you're right....maybe add the link....

Comment: In his answer, he said to change the swap usage to 30, but you said it's at 60, so I would suggest trying that, rebooting, and try again.

Comment: @Amstell done that already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I tested doing the exact same under a bigger (t1.small) instance and it worked fine. It looks like `R` does not play good with `EC2 t1.micro` instances.

The main difference between those 2 types of instances is that while the t1.micro has 0.6GB memory the t1.small has 1.7GB.

Couldn't test it under t2 type instances, they might perform better.

Answer (score 3):

Found a workaround. You can use Rscript form command line:

```
Rscript -e "install.packages('urca', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
```

Worked with AWS, Amazon Linux, t2.micro instance.