# 'Cannot allocate memory' while re-installing R package 'ddalpha' under Arch Linux

Tags: r, out-of-memory, archlinux

Upon updating to R 3.5.0 released 2 days ago, I had to re-install a lot of packages since all packages are now byte-compiled on installation.

I am unable to re-install the package `ddalpha` and get the error message:

```
Error in system2(file.path(R.home("bin"), "R"), c(if (nzchar(arch)) paste0("--arch=",  : 
  cannot popen ' '/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --no-save --slave 2>&1 < '/tmp/RtmpXs6prW/file285b65638b8d'', probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'
```

I have 16 Gb of RAM and have so far never gotten even close to using it all. That said, I do not know whether R has a full access to it.

I tried various workaround with no success:

- solution suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182054/cant-install-modules-cannot-allocate-memory-error):

`sudo Rscript -e "install.packages('ddalpha', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"`

- solution suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=236517):

`sudo R CMD INSTALL path-to-ddalpha_1.3.2.tar.gz`

In both cases, I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being unable to find a solution for this, I emailed the package maintainer. It turned out to be a bug: `ddalpha` byte-compiled extremely slowly and with the need a 4GB of RAM on Windows and macOS systems and the installation would fail altogether on linux systems.

The maintainer was phenomenal in contacting the R core team, looking for a fix, and getting back to me within 24 hours. The package is now fixed on CRAN and can be installed without issues.