# unable to install Rstudio packages in amazon EC2

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, package, rstudio-server

I have installed **amazon free trial linux t2.micro instance**, and I installed **RStudio**, but when I try to **install packages** on R I get this error:

> Warning in install.packages :
>         system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
>       Warning in install.packages :
>         installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status

Even when I run a simple in R.

> 1+1

I get the same error:

> system call failed: Cannot allocate memory

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136264/unable-to-install-packages-system-call-failed-cannot-allocate-memory-instal

Comment: @tobassist No, it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `t2.micro` instance. It has only `1GiB` of Memory.

**Choosing a larger instance would be the appropriate solution here.**
If you want to stick with the Free Tier eligible instance (`t2.micro`), one possible solution would be is to add some [swap space](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-swap-what-is.html).

Create a swap file for `1G` (increase the value of count accordingly to increase the swap file size)

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
```

And, add this entry to `/etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @franklinsijo, i added a swap space according to the more detailed solution in this link https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/